# Bar plot showing count by amount intervals

Tags: count, powerbi, bar-chart

So I have this column in Power BI:

Sales amount: 21, 22, 23, 45, 48, 50, 91, 100.

And all I would like to do is a plot where I can visualize a count by bins, so the expected result would be something that represents this table below:

Sales amount: 0-33, 34-66, 67-100

Count: 3, 3, 2.

What measure should I apply? I tried binning with the predefined options that come in Desktop, but so far haven't achieved what I want.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this *calculated column*

```
Bins = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    AND( 0 < Sales[Amount], Sales[Amount] <= 33 ), "0-33",
    AND(33 < Sales[Amount], Sales[Amount] <= 66 ), "33-66",
    AND(66 < Sales[Amount], Sales[Amount] <= 100 ), "66-100",
    "Outlier"
)
```

and this *measure*

```
Count = COUNTROWS(Sales)
```

and put it all together in a bar chart.

[image]